# How to get the background drawable of an Activity's window?

Tags: android

From an Activity, I can set the background drawable like this:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable)
```

But I can't find a method that retrieves the background drawable.

Is there one? If not, why not?

Comment: I think you can use `getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground();`

Comment: @rIHaNJiTHiN thanks. that works. can you reply as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground();` to retrieve the background drawable.